# Кнопка Одноклассники в Яндекс.Поделиться выдаёт 400 ошибку

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Пример страницы - https://stomatologclub.ru/stati/implantologiya-14/zuboalveolyarnoe-vydvizhenie-pri-planirovanii-detalnoj-implantacii-antogonistov-problema-ili-predskazuemoe-prepyatstvie-3165/

Страница доступна, кнопки других соц сетей замечательно работают.

Если взять ссылку (см. выше) и вставить в Одноклассники самому, то в счетчике кнопки Одноклассники это даже засчитывается - пример на этой же странице.